# The name 'SPUtility' does not exist in the current context

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, page-layout, sputility

I am using the following code in my page layout file but I am getting error.

CODE

```
<%= SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:NewsHeading", "myresourcefile", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID) %>
```

ERROR

> The name 'SPUtility' does not exist in the current context

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you able to get it in cs page ? Also check if Sharepoint namespace is registered in aspx page.

Comment: No idea what you mean by CS page. Yes I can see Sharepoint namespace mentioned on top of page but I think error is happening because of missing Microsoft.Sharepoint.Utilities namespace? If yes how do I define it? I mean I just write ; semicolon and then write the next namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the tag for Utilities registration on aspx page.

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" 
   Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" 
   Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Comment: Your code solved my problem but now I am getting error "The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context". I tried to add Threading Class above but no luck.